# Having trouble embedding base64 encoded png file into outlook signature via html

Tags: java, html, base64, png, signature

I'm having trouble embedding a base64 encoded png file into outlook signature via java/html. It recently stopped working the way it used to and I think some Windows update is the reason as to why it stopped working properly.

The picture's not properly embedded like shown [here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNcYA.png)

This method is writing the html content:

```
    private void changeHTMLContent(String HTMLFileName) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, SQLException {
    getHTMLContent(HTMLFileName);
    String fileLang = HTMLFileName.substring(11, 13).toUpperCase();
    langCfg = cfgReader.getLanguageConfig(fileLang);

    htmlString = htmlString.replace("[NAME]", uDataSet.getPersonalName());
    htmlString = htmlString.replace("[VORNAME]", uDataSet.getPersonalFirstName());
    htmlString = htmlString.replace("[FUNKTION]", uDataSet.getPersonalFunction());
    htmlString = htmlString.replace("[TELEFON]", langCfg.get("tel") + " " + uDataSet.getTelefonNumber());
    if (uDataSet.getTelefonMobil().length() != 0) {
        htmlString = htmlString.replace("[MOBILTELEFON]", langCfg.get("mobile") + " " + uDataSet.getTelefonMobil());
    } else {
        htmlString = htmlString.replace("[MOBILTELEFON]<br>", "\r");
    }
    if (uDataSet.getTelefonFax().length() != 0) {
        htmlString = htmlString.replace("[FAX]", langCfg.get("fax") + " " + uDataSet.getTelefonFax());
    } else {
        htmlString = htmlString.replace("[FAX]<br>", "\r");
    }
    htmlString = htmlString.replace("[EMAILT]", langCfg.get("email") + " ");
    htmlString = htmlString.replace("[EMAIL]", uDataSet.getPersonalEmail());
    htmlString = htmlString.replace("[EMAIL1]", uDataSet.getPersonalEmail());
    htmlString = htmlString.replace("[LOGO]", "<img border=0 width=180 height=70 src=" + "\"data:image/png;base64, " + imgLogoStr + "\">");
    if (arguments.get("name") != null) {
        String logoFile = System.getenv(cfgOutFilePath.get("userProfile")) + cfgOutFilePath.get("logofilepath") + arguments.get("name") + ".jpg";
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(logoFile));
        int height = image.getHeight();
        int width = image.getWidth();
        String imageString = encodeToString(image, "jpg");
        String HTMLLogoElement = "<tr>\n"
                + " <td width=" + width + " valign=top style='width:" + width + "pt;padding:0.5cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt; border:none;'>\n"
                + "     <p class=MsoNormal style='text-autospace:none'><b><i><span style='font-size:\n"
                + "       10.0pt;font-family:Arial'><img border=0 width=" + width + " height=" + height + "\n"
                + "       src=\"data:image/png;base64," + imageString + "\"></span></i></b></p>\n"
                + " </td>\n"
                + " </tr>";
        htmlString = htmlString.replace("[ADDITIONALLOGO]", HTMLLogoElement);
    } else {
        htmlString = htmlString.replace("[ADDITIONALLOGO]", "\r");
    }

}
```

Here's the html content:

```html
  <td width=318 valign=top style='width:238.65pt;border:none;border-top:solid windowtext 1.0pt;
  padding:0cm 5.4pt 0cm 5.4pt'><br>
  <p class=MsoNormal style='text-autospace:none'><b><i><span style='font-size:
  10.0pt;font-family:Arial'><img border=0 width=180 height=70 src="data:image/png;base64, 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"></span></i></b></p>
  </td>
```

Any help fixing this would be appreciated.

Comment: 'Asetronics' looks well encoded to me. Could be that Microsoft have broken the standard (wouldn't be the first time)

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/de-de/topic/ea15bbf7-9c46-6edc-569e-65e373317670

Comment: Deleting the Key BlockHTTPimage sadly doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Did you reboot?

Comment: To be precise there, wasn't even a key named BlockHTTPimage under: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\x.0\Common